# Working With Nested Lists LISP

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, nested-lists

I'm relatively new to lisp and am curious as to the best method for working with a nested list in the following context:

So, I have the following function:

```
(defun get-p0 (points)
    (loop for (label x y) in points
    ; collect (list (if (> x y) (+ 2 3))))
    collect (list (get-angle (first points) (second points))))
)
```

I call it like so:

```
(get-p0 '((A 5 2) (B 2 3) (C 8 9)))
```

What I've been trying to do is get the angle of each coordinate relative to the other coordinates. For example, the angle of AB, AC, BA, BC, CA, CB and print those out. The output I've been getting is as follows:

```
((161.56505) (161.56505) (161.56505))
```

That was really just for testing purposes at that point. Though what I'd really like to do is output the lowest and leftmost coordinate. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

I did very similar exercise some time ago. This looks like it could be of use to you:

```
;; Define struct `point'
(defstruct point x y)

;; Define methods specializing on `point'
(defgeneric add (a b))

(defgeneric subtract (a b))

(defgeneric distance (a b))

(defgeneric projection (a))

(defmethod add ((this point) (that point))
  (make-point :x (max (point-x this) (point-x that))
              :y (max (point-y this) (point-y that))))

(defmethod subtract ((this point) (that point))
  (make-point :x (min (point-x this) (point-x that))
              :y (min (point-y this) (point-y that))))

(defmethod distance ((this point) (that point))
  (let ((a (add this that)) (b (subtract this that)))
    (make-point :x (- (point-x a) (point-x b))
                :y (- (point-y a) (point-y b)))))

(defmethod projection ((this point))
  (sqrt (+ (expt (point-x this) 2) (expt (point-y this) 2))))

;; Define helper functions
(defun angle (a b c)
  (acos (/ (+ (* a a) (* b b) (- (* c c))) (* 2 a b))))

(defun radian->degree (radian) (/ (* 180 radian) pi))

;; Define struct `triangle'
(defstruct triangle
  (a nil :type (or null point))
  (b nil :type (or null point))
  (c nil :type (or null point)))

;; Define methods specializing on `triangle'
(defgeneric angles-of (triangle))

(defgeneric sides-of (triangle))

(defgeneric points-of (triangle))

(defmethod points-of ((this triangle))
  (let ((result (list (triangle-a this) (triangle-b this) (triangle-c this))))
    (nconc result result)))

(defmethod sides-of ((this triangle))
  (loop for (p . rest) on (points-of this)
     for i from 0 below 3
     collect (projection (distance p (car rest))) into result
     finally (return (nconc result result))))

(defmethod angles-of ((this triangle))
  (loop for (a b c) on (sides-of this)
       for i from 0 below 3
       collect (radian->degree (angle a b c)) into result
       finally (return (nconc result result))))

;; Create some test triangle
(defvar *pythagorean-triangle*
  (make-triangle :a (make-point :x 1 :y 2)
                 :b (make-point :x 4 :y 2)
                 :c (make-point :x 4 :y 6)))

;; Finally! don't forget to
(setf *print-circle* t)
;; so you can see circular lists' content
(angles-of *pythagorean-triangle*)

#1=(90.00000265626015d0 36.86989784081561d0 53.13009995842113d0 . #1#)
```

Few notes, I saw in another post there was some confusion about the form

```
(loop for <list-like expression> in some-list ...)
```

This `list-like expression` is what is usually called "destructuring bind". It is a limited pattern matching facility. Effectively, this is a pattern which maps symbols on you defined inside the pattern to whatever values found in the list you are iterating over.

So, for example, `(loop for (x y) on '(1 2 3 4))` will bind `x` and `y` to `1` and `2`, then `2`, `3`, then `3`, `4` and finally `4`, `nil`. Of course you can use more variables / you can use dotted list for the pattern etc.

Answer (score 1):

You are correctly binding the values every iteration using the form `for (x y z) in list`. But when you are doing the collect in the next line, you are taking values off the beginning of `list`. This value will never change over the evaluation of the loop.

You should change your code to look like this:

```
(defun get-p0 (points)
  (loop
      for (label x y) in points
      collect (list (get-angle x y))))
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your goal correctly, you want to consume a list like `'((A 5 2) (B 2 3) (C 8 9))` and return something like `(2 2)` (point a has A `y` of 2 and point B has an `x` of 2, and these are the lowest coordinates). I'd do something like

```
(loop for (_l x y) in lst
        minimizing y into min-y minimizing x into min-x
        finally (return (list min-x min-y)))
```

`loop` is a deep and powerful construct, so I'd recommend you read through the [relevant PCL chapter](http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/loop-for-black-belts.html) and the [`loop` spec](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_loop.htm#loop) (it's very easy to forget a directive that might turn out to be perfect for a given situation). If you're new to Lisp, you may want to take a look at [the entire book](http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/), actually.

Comment: @wvxvw - Yup; those particular keywords escaped me at the time. Amended.